# Add photo in Mapkit

Tags: iphone

I find the current Location on Mapkit. Now I need to add photo to my Mapkit current location. Does anyone have a sample code, or sample URL link?

Comment: Voting to close a request for third-party resources, which is off-topic.

Comment: I suppose this is the one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351358/swift-custom-mkpointannotation-with-image

Answer (score 0):

Try the *CSImageAnnotationView* from this project:

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108